# Ввод текста в RichTextBox WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013

Имеется следующий код:

```
    <Grid>
        <RichTextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <FlowDocument>
                <Paragraph>
                    <Run Text="RichTextBox"/>
                </Paragraph>
            </FlowDocument>
        </RichTextBox>
    </Grid>
```

В визуальном редакторе следующее:

[image]

Но после запуска программы, в реальности в окне следующее:

[image]

И как я только не пытался сделать вывод слова в одну строку - не получается. Соответственно, если во время исполнения программы вводить текст, то он также выводится по одному символу на строчку. Как с этим бороться?

Comment: @VladD, выводите ответ, чтобы тему "закрыть"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что-то не так с лэйаутом. Попробуйте выяснить, где расположен какой элемент, при помощи [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/)'а (незаменимая утилита). При необходимости укажите правильную ширину или `HorizontalAlignment`.

Кажется, у `FlowDocument` было своё нестандартное представление о выравнивании.

Comment: Спасибо. Snoop действительно помог. Проблема оказалась в глючности RichTextBox при его использовании в качестве Item в коллекции ListBox'а. Если явно не указать Width элементов в ListBox'е, а просто HorizontalContentAligment=Stretch, то RichTextBox шириной как надо, но его содержимое косячит. Указав Width явно все косяки пропадают. Естественно пришлось добавить обработчик событий Window.SizeChanged.

Comment: @krupennikov: Вместо обработки `SizeChanged` можно по идее просто указать, например,

    Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=<тут имя Grid'а>}"